# Android keypad overlaying on textbox issue

Tags: c#, android, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

We developing mobile application using mvc and jquery mobile in that when I click on the Textbox field in an android tab(10 inch tab) the android keypad appears. The keypad is hiding my textbox field, so I am not able to see the words that I am entering into the Textbox. Keypad overlays the text box.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Below is my Textbox Code.

```
<div class="field" style="width:35%;font-size:1.75em;padding-top:1.5%">
            <input type="text" id="txtDPScanDirectLoc" autofocus="autofocus" />
   </div>
```

Comment: ya its a very needed and important question

Comment: Is there overflow is hidden in css? Try this.


$(document).on("pageinit", function (event) {
    $('input').on('focusin', function (event) {

        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });

});

Answer (score 0):

You could try this command:

```
"adjustPan"
```

Using this, the activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Is there overflow is hidden in css? Try this. $(document).on("pageinit", function (event) { $('input').on('focusin', function (event) { $(document).scrollTop(0); }); });